# How fast can $|x|$ be approximated by polynomials on $[-1,1]$?

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

Jackson's theorem states that if a function $f$ satisfies
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le M|x-y|,$$
then it can be uniformly approximated at the rate
$$|f(x)-P_n(x)|\le \frac{M}{2(n+1)} = O(1/n),$$
where $P_n(x)$ is the best uniform approximation polynomial of $f(x)$ on $[-1,1]$.

My question is when $f(x) = |x|$, can the convergence rate $O(1/n)$ be exceeded? In other words, can one construct a series of polynomials $Q_n(x)$ such that
$$|f(x)-Q_n(x)| < O(1/n),$$
(such as $O(1/n^2)$)?

I tried to use the truncated Taylor expansion of
$$(1-(1-x^2))^{1/2} = 1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n-3)!!}{2^nn!}(1-x^2)^n,$$
but it seems this method can only obtain an $O(1/\sqrt{n})$ rate, even worse than $O(1/n)$. The Bernstein approximation of $|x|$ also seems to be $O(1/\sqrt{n})$. I have no idea of how to construct alternative good approximations.

Comment: According to https://mathoverflow.net/a/295684/116247, $O(1/n)$ is best possible.

Comment: Taylor is far from optimal.  A method to get a best approximation of specified degree is [Remez' Alrogithm(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm)].  However, for pathological (non-smooth) stuff it converges slowly. The smaller the order where non-smoothness kicks in, the slower the convergence to the MiniMax.

Comment: @Martin R Thanks! Could you please post a (English) reference on the proof of this statement? It seems no proof is given in this link, and the reference mentioned there is the Bernstein's paper written in French.

Comment: @qdmj: I am afraid that I cannot help. I found that MO thread with some Googling, but I do not have the articles mentioned in the answer, nor am I an expert in that area.